# Android service can not be uninstalled

Tags: android, cordova, android-service

I have an android app which is made by cordova. For test reasons I made a service and used it in my app that toasts some data on screen and my clients installed that version. Now I don't need that service and want to remove it, but unfortunately it didn't get removed on devices that installed that old version of my app. I installed my new version on a new device and there was not any effect of the service. What should I do to get rid of that service. I appreciate your help and maybe similar experiences.

Comment: @Hosein As far as i know you can disable the service manually in device but i m afraid you will be able to uninstall it as it may require rooting of the device..

Comment: Is the service bundled inside the old app or it's a separate app?